# LINQ Select distinct on different variables

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query which selects a list of my class. It looks like so:

```
IQueryable<ClaimsBySupplierAggregate> agg = 
  (from d in alliance.SupplierSearchByReviewPeriod
   where d.ClientID == ClientID && ReviewPeriodIDs.Contains((int)d.ReviewPeriodID)

   select new ClaimsBySupplierAggregate {
       Amount = d.Amount,
       StatusCategoryID = d.StatusCategoryID,
       DeptName = d.DepartmentName,
       APLReason = d.APLReason,
       Area = d.AreaDesc,
       StatusCategoryDesc = d.StatusCategoryDesc,
       Agreed = d.Agreed
   });
```

Later on in the application I select each variable and get the distinct values like this:

```
SupplierModel.APLReason = agg.Select(r => r.APLReason).Distinct().ToList();
SupplierModel.AreaDesc = agg.Select(r => r.Area).Distinct().ToList();
SupplierModel.DeptName = agg.Select(r => r.DeptName).Distinct().ToList();
SupplierModel.StatCatDes = aggg.Select(r => r.StatusCategoryDesc).Distinct().ToList();
```

Is there a way to do this in one LINQ statement?

Comment: Im sorry, I just didn't paste the whole method. I will ammend

Comment: I don't see you getting the distinct value anywhere. Your code is getting all values

Comment: I think he means "different" , not "distinct" :-)

Comment: No I mean distinct. Sorry a co-worker thought he had an idea, we changed the code and I forget to undo them. Sorry. Check now

Answer (score 2):

You could using Aggregate, but you would need a complex object for the seed, which brings you to the same complexity of code. I think that for this particular case, using LInQ enters the Golden Hammer antipattern. Just use an old fashioned loop and four HashSets instead of Lists and you are done and the code is more readable and your intention clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this then customize the code follow your expectation.
Or you can use group by.

```
public class LinqTest
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            LinqTest obj2 = obj as LinqTest;
            if (obj2 == null) return false;
            return id == obj2.id;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return id;
        }
    }

    List<LinqTest> uniqueIDs = myList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a contrived way to do this:

```
from d in alliance.SupplierSearchByReviewPeriod
where d.ClientID == ClientID && ReviewPeriodIDs.Contains((int)d.ReviewPeriodID)
group d by 0 into g
select new
{
    APLReasons = g.Select(d => d.APLReason).Distinct(),
    AreaDescs = g.Select(d => d.Area).Distinct(),
    DeptNames = g.Select(d => d.DeptName).Distinct(),
    StatusCategoryDescs = g.Select(d => d.StatusCategoryDesc).Distinct(),
}
```

The part `group d by 0 into g` creates one group of all items, from which you can subsequently query any aggregate you want.

BUT...

...this creates a very inefficient query with `UNION`s and (of course) `DISTINCT`s. It's probably better (performance-wise) to simply get the flat data from the database and do the aggregations in subsequent code.